# How to have multiple layers of hasMany() relation for Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, has-many

Let say I have tables like the following:

```
order
 order_id | customer_name | delivery_address        
 1        | David         | ABC Road, DEF district 
...........Some other record ..............

order_dish
order_id | dish_id | dish_name
1        | 1       | chicken wing
1        | 2       | meat pie
1        | 3       | onion ring
...........Some other record ..............

dish_ingredient
dish_id | ingredient
1       | chicken wing
1       | salt
1       | oil
2       | pork meat
2       | flour
3       | onion
...........Some other record ..............
```

In Laravel 5, if I want to get all dishes of an order, I can do:

```
$order = Order::hasMany('App\OrderDish', 'order_id')->get();
```

Is there a way I can get all ingredients needed for an order in one line?

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through , this should solve your issue.

Comment: You need to define a hasMany OrderDish inside the Order model. Also the orderDish model should have a hasMany dishIngredients (if I understood correctly)

Comment: The code you posted won't get you "all dishes of an order", because you're not passing order ID anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. You define it using **hasManyThrough()** method of your model.

First, define the relation in your **Order** model:

```
class Order extends Model {
  public function ingredients() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\DishIngredient', 'App\OrderDish', 'order_id', 'dish_id');
  }
}
```

With such a relation defined, you'll be able to get ingredients for given order with:

```
$ingredients = $order->ingredients;
```